Quartz.NET not loading any jobs defined in the SQL Server database
I have defined a job and trigger in a SQL Server database, but cannot get the job to load or trigger to fire. I'm just wondering if someone can guide me towards the resolution to this, I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, but just cannot spot it.
I have been all over the Quartz.NET documentation but may be misunderstanding some settings.
Any and all help greatly appreciated.
You can see some of the output from the start up below, and you can see the message about "adding 0 job, 0 triggers"
Using job store 'Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX', supports persistence: True, clustered: True
{"@t":"2024-07-08T14:10:24.3246282Z","@mt":"Using job store 'Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX', supports persistence: True, clustered: True","SourceContext":"Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory","SFTPService":"SFTPService"}
{"@t":"2024-07-08T14:10:24.3328792Z","@mt":"Adding 0 jobs, 0 triggers.","SourceContext":"Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor","SFTPService":"SFTPService"}

Below is the startup code I have implemented to initialise Quartz, it's running in a C# console application.
I have all configuration in the startup and I am not using any settings in the appsettings.json file.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Setup Quartz the timer scheduling library
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt =>
        {
            opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });
services.AddQuartz(q=>
        {
            q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
            {
                s.UseProperties = true;
                s.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                s.UseSqlServer(sqlServer =>
                {
                    sqlServer.ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Quartz") ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Quartz connection string");
                    sqlServer.TablePrefix = "QRTZ_";

                });
                s.UseClustering(c =>
                {
                    c.CheckinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    c.CheckinMisfireThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                });
            });
        });

I have created some jobs in the database using these scripts:
INSERT INTO QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS 
    (SCHED_NAME, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP, JOB_CLASS_NAME, IS_DURABLE, IS_NONCONCURRENT, IS_UPDATE_DATA, REQUESTS_RECOVERY, JOB_DATA)
VALUES 
    ('SFTPService', 'SFTPDownloadJobName', 'SFTPJobGroup', 'MyCompany.SFTP.WorkerLibrary.SFTPDownloadJob, MyCompany.SFTP.WorkerLibrary', 1, 0, 0, 0, NULL);


INSERT INTO QRTZ_TRIGGERS 
    (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, JOB_NAME, JOB_GROUP, DESCRIPTION, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PREV_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY, TRIGGER_STATE, TRIGGER_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, CALENDAR_NAME, MISFIRE_INSTR, JOB_DATA)
VALUES 
    ('SFTPService', 'FrequentTriggerName', 'FrequentTriggerGroup', 'SFTPDownloadJobName', 'SFTPJobGroup', 'Fires every 20 seconds', NULL, NULL, 5, 'WAITING', 'CRON', DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01', GETDATE()), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);


INSERT INTO QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS 
    (SCHED_NAME, TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, CRON_EXPRESSION, TIME_ZONE_ID)
VALUES 
    ('SFTPService', 'FrequentTriggerName', 'FrequentTriggerGroup', '0/20 * * * * ?', NULL);

DECLARE @jsonData NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "SftpHostName": "eu-central-1.sftpcloud.io",
    "SftpPortNumber": "22",
    "SftpUserName": "*********************",
    "SftpPassword": "***********************",
    "SftpRemoteDirectory": "/",
    "SftpLocalDirectory": "",
    "SftpFileNameOrPattern": "test.txt"
}';
DECLARE @jobData VARBINARY(MAX) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @jsonData);

UPDATE QRTZ_TRIGGERS
SET JOB_DATA = @jobData
WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'SFTPService' 
  AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'FrequentTriggerName' 
  AND TRIGGER_GROUP = 'FrequentTriggerGroup';


The query to obtain the next trigger to fire searches by QRTZ_TRIGGERS.NEXT_FIRE_TIME. That's null for your trigger, so it won't be fired. Note that Quartz.NET stores times in Ticks (and not as a Unix Timestamp). Usual practice would be to create jobs and triggers with Quartz.NET.

Thanks for the pointer @PhilRoss, I did not realise that declaring the job and trigger in the actual startup would persist those details in the database.
The other question is how do I make the job and trigger scheduling configurable, but that is for a different question I think, once I have pondered on this some more.

To answer my own question so anyone else who was as confused as I was, simply doing the following will create the job in the correct tables in the database.
Thanks to @Phil Ross for his pointer.
So the complete code to create the job and trigger in the startup is below. The follow on question is how to make this configurable to the customer, when additional jobs or triggers need to be defined, so I will need to research that piece.
services.AddQuartz(q=>
{
    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
        s.UseSqlServer(sqlServer =>
        {
            sqlServer.ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Quartz") ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Quartz connection string");
            sqlServer.TablePrefix = "QRTZ_";

        });
        s.UseClustering(c =>
        {
            c.CheckinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            c.CheckinMisfireThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        });
        q.AddJob<SFTPDownloadJob>(j => j
                .StoreDurably()
                .WithIdentity("SFTPDownloadJob")
                .WithDescription("This job downloads files from an SFTP server"));
        q.AddTrigger(t => t
                .WithIdentity("SFTPDownloadJobTrigger")
                .ForJob("SFTPDownloadJob")
                .WithCronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"));

    });
});


